# Jquery-File-Upload Send Additional Parameters With Form Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, jquery-file-upload

In my application, I am uploading multiple files using the jquery plugin. In order to make file uploads in parallel I initialize the plugin with the following parameters.

```
    $('#fileupload')
        .fileupload({
            multipart: true,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/upload/",
            limitConcurrentUploads: 8,
            sequentialUploads: false,
            progressInterval: 100,
            maxChunkSize: 0,
            add: function(e, data) {
                $('#filelistholder').removeClass('hide');
                data.context = $('<div />').text(data.files[0].name).appendTo('#filelistholder');
                $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:0%"></div></div>')
                    .appendTo(data.context);
                $('#btnUploadAll')
                    .click(function () {
                        data.submit();
                    });
            },
            done: function(e, data) {
                data.context.text(data.files[0].name + '... Completed');
                $('</div><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width:100%"></div></div>')
                    .appendTo(data.context);
            },
            progressall: function(e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                if (progress > 0) console.log("progressall -> "+progress);
                $('#overallbar').css('width', progress + '%');
            },
            progress: function(e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                if (progress > 0) console.log("progress -> " + progress);
                data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
```

WebApi action to which requests from the extension are directed is as follows.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
    {
    ...
    }
```

I can easily transfer the files in inconcurrently way to my api function. But I also want to send additional parameters to my WebApi with submit function of form.

I have changed my api function like below.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Upload([FromBody]int testParam)
    {
     ...
    }
```

And tried to send tu this function from button click with jquery.

```
    $('#fileupload')
     .bind('fileuploadsubmit',
         function (e, data) {
             data.formData = { testParam: 1 };
         });
```

I can see form parts in data parameter but I cannot add new value and catch it from my api function. How can I do this ?

Comment: i think you should user `beforeSend:`  in `$('#fileupload')`.

Comment: But I cannot find a callback named beforesend in jquery-file-upload documentation @codenut

Comment: ok i thought it supports all ajax property, my bad.

Comment: but that's strange you code is as per there documentation i thing you should try their 1 st example  directly adding  `formData = { testParam: 1 } ` to `.fileupload`  something like this as per their documentation  `$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   formData = { testParam: 1 }; ...........
});`